# Talmud bavli on Kindle

Tags: product-recommendation, talmud-gemara

I'm looking to view Talmud bavli in standard Oz v'hdar daf format on Kindle. Has anyone seen this?

I know how to do this; however, I am wondering if someone has already done this and can provide the results, whether for free or commercially.

Comment: It isn't very useful. because of the size of the kindle, you must zoom in and out constantly, which as you know in the kindle is annoying because of the e-ink display. On the Kindle fire it might be another story...

Comment: @Mendy there's a larger Kindle (10" I think?) that they developed with textbooks in mind.  It might work ok on that for some people.

Comment: http://halakhah.com/

Answer (score 1):

It'll take a couple of steps, but it's doable (and I've done it on my Android tablet).

1. Download the PDFs of תלמוד בבלי from [Hebrewbooks.org](http://hebrewbooks.org/).
2. Put them on your Kindle, either by downloading them directly to the Kindle, or by putting them on a micro-SD card.
3. It's a Kindle, so it *should* have an e-reader built in, but make sure you have an app that's able to read PDFs.
4. Done! Enjoy your portable Shas :)

...I took a bit of a shortcut, as the full set of Shas has been circulating yeshiva for a while, so I didn't have to track down the individual volumes and download them, but it shouldn't be too hard to do.

---

Above is the free version. If you don't mind paying, as you mentioned in your question, you can buy a Nook Naki, which I've seen advertised in seforim stores (though I haven't spotted it online). The idea is a Nook (which is an e-reader, similar to the Kindle) which is incapable of accessing the internet, and contains many many seforim (more than just Shas).
I've never used one, and I don't think I know anyone who has one, but that product's out there.

Comment: You virtually know someone who has one.  Although I rarely use it, I got it as a gift.  I only found it useful for airplanes.  Otherwise I prefer the real thing.

Comment: "I know how to do this however I am wondering if someone has already done this and can provide the results" says the question. Your answers seems to start at the your horizontal rule: the rest doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @YeZ `:-)` [15]

Comment: @msh210 What does "provide the results" mean? ....should I upload my folder of gemara PDFs to Dropbox for the OP to download?

Comment: I assume that's what was meant, yes.